# Cross filesystem move in Rust similar to shutil.move in Python

Tags: rust

In Python, there are two functions for moving files. For my needs, they have one big difference in functionality:

- `os.rename`: This only works if the destination is on the same filesystem as the source.
- `shutil.move`: This works across filesystems.

In Rust, there is `std::fs::rename` for the former, but as far as I'm aware, there is nothing for the latter in the standard library.

Is there a function I'm missing? If not, is there a crate that does this that I have missed?

For now, I'm doing something like this:

```rust
use std::path::Path;

pub fn move_file<P: AsRef<Path>, Q: AsRef<Path>>(from: P, to: Q) -> std::io::Result<()> {
    match std::fs::rename(&from, &to) {
        Ok(result) => Ok(result),
        Err(_) => {
            std::fs::copy(&from, &to)?;
            std::fs::remove_file(from)?;
            Ok(())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `shutil.move` on a regular file just tries to rename and performs copy followed by delete if it fails, similar to what you wrote. Of course, it also handles directories.

Comment: Yeah I thought so too,  I suppose this is just a case of "batteries not quite as included" with the Rust standard library. I understand not putting this in the library I suppose, it's a bit awkward, e.g. what should the errors look like, what if removing the file fails, etc.

Comment: @DanielPorteous If you are on nightly, you can do that only on [`ErrorKind::CrossesDevices`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/enum.ErrorKind.html#variant.CrossesDevices), which I believe is the error returned in these cases.

Comment: Interesting, I suppose once that error kind is stabilized you could make a case for including a `move` / `move_file` function in the standard library. I'm on stable for now though.

Comment: I guess there is a crate for this